# How to unit test django application using jena-fuseki?

Tags: django, sparql, python-unittest, jena, fuseki

My django application uses sparql with jena-fuseki RDF-database. How should I run my unit tests as thete's hardly any information in availble for creatig in-memory jena database for a django unittesting ?  So far I've been just running a local fuseki-server, but that's not the way unit testing should be done, right ?